# Percentage similarity between two strings

Tags: c++, string, percentage

(I'm a beginner in c++). I already have correct number of mismatches, and everything in my program works fine, but when I try to actually calculate it the percentage comes up as 0. This is part of my code (specifically the only part giving trouble). Can someone possibly explain to me what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
    if(input.length() >= input2.length())
    {
        percentage = (uiLevenshteinDistance(input,input2)/input.size())*100;  
        cout << "These sequences are " << percentage << "% similar." << endl; 
    }
    else if(input2.length() >= input.length())
    {
        percentage = (uiLevenshteinDistance(input,input2)/input2.size())*100; 
        cout << "These sequences are " << percentage << "% similiar." << endl;   
    }
```

Comment: Integer division. `1/2` yields `0`.

Comment: Are you trying to divide two integers? If you want a floating point result, you need to cast at least one of the integers to `float` or `double` first.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: @PeterWood This is part of my code. I did use Lev Distance, I just didn't need to type out my whole code when the problem only dealt with this portion.

Comment: @user2338411 If you'd reduced your code to a [simple example](http://sscce.org), the question title wouldn't have been about percentage similarity of strings, it would have been about integer division, and you'd have had a better chance of working it out yourself, or else finding an answer by searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your numerator or your denominator in the division is a double/float otherwise you will always get 0 from a division resulting in a number < 1.

Something like `(double)uiLevenshteinDistance(input,input2)/input.size())` will do.

Comment: In cases where you want percentage (which he does), the simplest solution is to multiply the numerator by `100.0` _before_ doing the division.  The double in the multiplication forces all further operations to use `double`.  (And yes, it's very counter-intuitive that `100.0 * x / y` gives radically different results than `x / y * 100.0`.  But C++ isn't alone in this.)